# "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this action on a sealed instance." FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, android, google-play

I am getting this error on pre-launch report from playstore console.
I am not able to generate this crash on any real device I try.
The device from pre-launch report is Samsung s9 (Android 8.0).

This is the stacktrace :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this action on a sealed instance.
    at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.enforceNotSealed(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:2992)
    at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.setSource(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:818)
    at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.setSource(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:795)
    at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.obtain(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:3008)
    at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:7897)
    at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:7883)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchDescendantsOfRealNode(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1051)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchAccessibilityNodeInfos(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:876)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.findAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityIdUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:199)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:1225)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Dont know how much its helps but  I added             webView.setAccessibilityDelegate(new View.AccessibilityDelegate()); 
this in my webview and the error went away from playstore.

Comment: Hi Bipin, where did you add this line?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more code, I'd recommend looking through the following links to try and determine an exact cause.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57964014/5779200

> When updating values for AccessibilityNodeInfo it has been seen that calling `.getClassName()` to see if the value is NULL can help prevent this error.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32829963/5779200

> Similar to the previous, If you are changing the text of an `accessibilityNodeInfo` you can check to see if it's sealed by calling [`isSealed()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/4213804/core/java/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.java#1081). on the AccessibilityNodeInfo object